# How to define array type containing mixed types with incompatible properties?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, ajv

I want to validate a configuration using Ajv. The configuration represents column headers ( in a HTML table ). A single column might have multiple fields like title etc.

```
interface ColumnConfiguration { 
  fieldOnlyColumnsCanHave: string; 
}
```

with the schema

```
const columnConfigurationSchema: JSONSchemaType<ColumnConfiguration> = {
  type: 'object',
  properties: {
    fieldOnlyColumnsCanHave: { type: 'string' },
  },
  required: ['fieldOnlyColumnsCanHave'],
  additionalProperties: false,
};
```

I also want to support column groups ( I guess it's called stacked headers ? ), those must have at least one children, additional groups or columns.

```
interface ColumnGroupConfiguration {
  children: (ColumnGroupConfiguration | ColumnConfiguration)[]; 
}
```

with the schema **( this might be wrong here )**

```
const columnGroupConfigurationSchema: JSONSchemaType<ColumnGroupConfiguration> =
  {
    $id: 'ColumnGroupConfiguration',
    type: 'object',
    properties: {
      children: {
        type: 'array',
        minItems: 1,
        items: {
          anyOf: [
            { $ref: 'ColumnGroupConfiguration' },
            columnConfigurationSchema,
          ],
        },
      },
    },
    required: ['children'],
    additionalProperties: false,
  };
```

The root schema expects a list of columns and column groups

```
const columnsConfigurationSchema: JSONSchemaType<(ColumnGroupConfiguration | ColumnConfiguration)[]> = {
  type: 'array',
  items: {
    anyOf: [columnGroupConfigurationSchema, columnConfigurationSchema],
  },
  minItems: 1,
};
```

You can see a playground for this at [**stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-myf56k?file=columnGroupConfigurationSchema.ts)

Unfortunately I get a TS compile error for `columnGroupConfigurationSchema`

> The types of 'properties.children' are incompatible between these types

Do you know how to fix the schema / TS error?

---

A quick fix would be to cast the variable `columnGroupConfigurationSchema` to `as JSONSchemaType<ColumnGroupConfiguration>`. This seems to work in the playground but I don't know if this is a "good" solution.